# Can we make a new method for Dataset in AchartEngine?

Tags: java, android, date, dataset, achartengine

I have 3 Array list  one is for value one is for date and one is for title.
I want to set it in the dataset but when i set it in

```
 mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset( legendArray,arrayforDateticks, values), renderer);
```

Also i am using this for Xtitle Date.

```
List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>(arrayforDateticks.size());
String[] date = new String[stockArr.length];
for(int i= 0; i<stockArr.length; i++)
 {
      date[i] = stockArr[i] ; 
 }
 for(int i=0 ; i < titles.length; i++)
 {
    x.add(new double[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35});
  }
 for(int i=0;i<date.length;i++)
 {
     renderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, date[i]);
 }
```

It throws null pointer exception when rendering.addXtextlabel Why it so?

Comment: check initialization of `rendering`.

Comment: please ellaborate your comment

Comment: Please post the exception. Otherwise, nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said hoveryspicy, renderer do not seems to be initialized.

you need to put something like  :

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

before trying to add any text label...